# UITableViewCell accessory slide in and out direction when in edit mode

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UISwitch for UITableViewCell.accessoryView and a UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator for the UITableViewCell.editingAccessoryType in a cell. Like this:

```
cell.accessoryView = switchView;
cell.editingAccessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

When the table goes into edit mode the UISwitch slides off to the right of the cell before the Disclosure indicator appears. I'd like the UISwitch and the disclosure indicator to slide in from the right moving left when the table goes into edit mode. Apple's own Clock app does exactly this when you edit the list of Alarm Times.

I found I can make the accessory slide in from the right when I reverse the switch and disclosure indicator such that:

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
cell.editingAccessoryView = switchView;
```

However this isn't what I want as I want the non edit mode to show the switch. How can I get it to do what I want like Apple's Clock app?

Answer (score -1):

Place your UISwitch as a subview of cells contentView

Comment: That doesn't help, the UISwitch gets slid to the right as the editing delete icon slides in on left side of cell. The disclosure fades in. I'd like them both the slide in from right like in the Clock app.

Comment: Set frame of switch in tableviewCell subclasses layoutSubviews method